# Celery doesn't take multiple tasks when worker started from service

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

My Python Flask application supports some long-running tasks, which are invoked using API or CURL calls from some other systems.

When I execute the following command by manually entering it into a terminal, it works great.

`celery worker -A manage.celery --loglevel=info -f log/celery.log`

Now, I want to create a service for the server, where if the system restarts, this celery worker should start on its own. But, when following command is executed from service, it doesn't take any new tasks from the queue.

`celery worker -A manage.celery --pool=solo --loglevel=info -f log/celery.log`

I can see CURL call hitting server, but the underlying tasks are not getting started in celery.

Any idea on how this can be resolved?

Comment: I would suggest you keep them separate. They're related, but ultimately different. All you're going to do is complicate your setup. May I suggest a shell/batch script that does it for you, example (*nix): `service restart flaskapp; service restart celery`. Remember that when restarting celery, when you send it a `ctrl-c (SIGINT)` celery will finish the current job at hand and take on no more jobs, after it will quit (this also applies to flask). So if your script quits celery and flask and then starts them both up, it will work nicely.

Comment: There's [some documentation on the topic](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html) already... This being said, if you already use supervisor, just adding a supervisor conf for your worker process works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an **issue** in command written in services file. My command in services file was `celery worker -A manage.celery --pool=solo --loglevel=info -f log/celery.log`

Whereas, on terminal I had used `celery worker -A manage.celery --loglevel=info -f log/celery.log` command. Here `--pool=solo` wasn't used, and thus multiple tasks could be executed.

Updated the command in services file, and it started executing multiple tasks there as well.

In-depth understanding of execution pools can be taken from this [link](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/).